# how to make Highcharts React redraw without changing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I need highcharts to adapt its width to the parent's width. So if we change the parent's width without changing the data, the chart should resize.
But since the data is the same, it doesn't happen.

It seems to work if we resize the browser's screen, but that's not what we need.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const LineChart = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(null);
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    },
    series: [{ data: [1, 2, 3] }],
  });

  const handleWidth = () => {
    const w = getRandomIntInclusive(100, 500);
    setWidth(w);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width }}>
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />
      <button onClick={handleWidth}>change container width</button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<LineChart />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here's a link to a "not working" example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xhcmx4?file=index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Highcharts API:

> **reflow([e])**
>
> Reflows the chart to its container. By default, the chart reflows automatically to its container following a window.resize event, as per
> the chart.reflow option. However, there are no reliable events for div
> resize, so if the container is resized without a window resize event,
> this must be called explicitly.

As a solution, call `reflow` method after `width` change.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = chartComponent.current?.chart;

    if (chart) chart.reflow(false);
  }, [width]);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zydh8m?file=index.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

Answer (score 1):

If for any reason you can not use the `.reflow` solution from [ppotaczek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72199959/2440049) you can send a resize Event to the window object when resizing the container div.

```js
   setTimeout(() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')));
```

HighCharts listens to that event and will then repaint itself.

---

**[Stackblitz Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yypd36?file=index.js)**